# problem with a jpa query based on the method name with condition on a super class@mappedSuperclass property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have an audit base class annotated with @MappedSuperclass that contains the createdDate property, a girl class that contains the StationReference property, how to make a request based on the method name in jpa in the repository of the daughter. i want to retrieve List of Buytrace according to the parameters createdDate and stationReference

i tried this

```
 public interface BuyTraceRepository extends JpaRepository<BuyTrace, Long> {
     List<BuyTrace> findBuyTraceByCreatedDateAndStationReference(Date from,String ref);
     @Query("select b from BuyTrace b where b.createdDate = :date AND b.stationReference = :ref")
     List<BuyTrace> findCreatedDateAndStationReference(@Param("date") Date date,@Param("ref") String ref);

     List<BuyTrace> findBuyTraceByCreatedDateBetween(Date from, Date to);
}
```

The Entity class (daughter class)`enter code here`

```
 public class BuyTrace extends AuditableEntity {

      private String stationReference;
}
```

The mother class

```
 @MappedSuperclass
 @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
 public abstract class AuditableEntity<U> { 
     @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
     @CreatedDate
     @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
     public Date createdDate; 
  }
```

the first two methods of the repository do not work but curiously the method between two date(the last) works perfectly. I do not understand anything please help me

Comment: I suspect you will find the solution in your method naming. `findBuyTraceByCreatedDateBetween` is a 'valid' naming for spring-data-jpa to figure out what you're trying to do. `findBuyTraceByCreatedDateAndStationReference` should possibly be something like `findBuyTraceByCreatedDateGreaterThanAndStationReference` and the other one is at the very least missing the `by` keyword.

Comment: i don't put by? yes it is done voluntarily because I use a jpql for that method and findBuytraceByCreatedDateGreaterThanAndStationReference 
this method will give me the buytrace higher on my date it's not what i want, i want all buytrace that match my date and reference

Comment: Frankly I am desperate and no one is trying to help me. where are the stackoverflow genie

Comment: So when you say "the first two methods of the repository do not work", what does that mean? Is there an error or are you not getting the results that you expect? If the former, please add the error message, if the latter, I would suggest you add logging statements to understand what date you are comparing and what is in the database. Since you are looking for equality, consider how `Date` is actually a timestamp and how a 1ms difference might no longer match what is in your database. Issues will ensue with timezones, etc. You could use `TemporalType.DATE` to reduce resolution.